# How to bind a ObservableCollection of type string to Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I have a rather simple query, I have a `ObservableCollection` of type `string` called **Complaints**. Now I would like to bind this `ObservableCollection` to a `DataGrid` with two columns: a checkbox template column, and `Complaint` column which contains the complaint. I would want to know how to achieve this? I'm using MVVM. I have set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to `Complaints` but cannot see the data as I do not know what to put in `Binding` for the second column of the `DataGrid`. How do I do this?

> My View Model

```
public class MyViewModel() : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
     private ObservableCollection<string> _complaints;

     public ObservableCollection<string> Complaints
     {
          get
          {
               return _complaints;
          }
          set
          {
               _complaints = value;
               NotifyPropertyChanged("Complaints");
          }
     }

}
```

> My Datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg_pc" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Complaints}" Grid.Column="0">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        //Checkbox Template Column.
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="6.5217*">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox x:Name="cb_datagrid" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>

        //This is the column, where I need to display the **Complaint** Collection
        <DataGridTextColumn Width="93.4782*"Header="Complaints" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: well, if you can provide some code it would be usefull. But here a guess: did you set the grids DataContext to "Complaints"?

Comment: Added the code.

Comment: anything in the Output window about data errors?

Comment: No, nothing regarding this.

Comment: I can see the datagrid rows in the grid, as data exists, but cannot actually see the data, because there isn't any binding in the column with the `Complaints` header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the Binding property of the DataGridTextColumn. This binding is relative to the data items of the source collection. Since your source collection itself is the item you want to display in the column, the binding will be to the item itself.

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="93.4782*" Header="Complaints" Binding="{Binding}"/>
```

or equivalently:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Width="93.4782*" Header="Complaints" Binding="{Binding Path=.}"/>
```

Typically for a DataGrid you would be binding to a collection of objects with various properties you want to display each in a column, not just a collection of strings.

**Model:**

```
public class Complaint : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ComplaintsViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Complaint> Complaints { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

**View:**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Complaints}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="Active" Binding="{Binding IsActive}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Content" Binding="{Binding Content}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGrid/>
```

Comment: Yes thank you, this did it. Yes, my other datagrids are all binded to collection of objects, it was only this one.